# Need help understanding why this invalid C++ code compiles successfully

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compile correctly for me in some environments (e.g. on [compiler explorer with GCC 9.3.0](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09std::string+name%3D%22aakash%22%3B%0A%09name.erase(name.begin()%2B2,+name.cend())%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.32798325191905,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+9.3%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+9.3+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:22.67448036592636,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g93,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.3+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.99753638215459,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)) and complains in others (CentOS 7.9.2009 (Core), GCC 9.3.1).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string name="aakash";
    name.erase(name.begin()+2, name.cend());
    return 0;
}
```

When I get an error, the error is:

```
test.cpp:6:40: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator)'
    6 |  name.erase(name.begin()+2, name.cend());
      |                                        ^
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4698:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
 4698 |       erase(size_type __pos = 0, size_type __n = npos)
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4698:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'}
 4698 |       erase(size_type __pos = 0, size_type __n = npos)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4714:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]'
 4714 |       erase(iterator __position)
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4714:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4734:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]'
 4734 |       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last);
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:4734:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from '__normal_iterator<const char*,[...]>' to '__normal_iterator<char*,[...]>'
 4734 |       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last);
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

The error looks reasonable to me because, as per [C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), both arguments to `std::basic_string::erase` should either be of type `iterator` or `const_iterator`.

So, when it works (e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09std::string+name%3D%22aakash%22%3B%0A%09name.erase(name.begin()%2B2,+name.cend())%3B%0A%09return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.32798325191905,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+9.3%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+9.3+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:22.67448036592636,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g93,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.3+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.99753638215459,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)), what allows it to work?

Comment: Then you should file a gcc bug. Did you check with other compilers?

Comment: ehm.... `#include <string>`. Also conflict in using the namespace std and in your example you use `std::` anyway. This works for me: `#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name="aakash";
    name.erase(name.begin()+2, name.cend());
    
    cout << name << endl;
    return 0;
}` Returns : `aa`

Comment: iterators can convert to const iterators. Do you still get the error when you do include `<string>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++11, **both** arguments to the two-iterator overload of `std::string::erase()` are **`const_iterator`**. See form #3 on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) (the one you linked in your question).

Further, the C++11 Standard *requires* that a conatiner's `iterator` types are convertible to the equivalent `const_iterator`.

From [this Draft C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements), in **§23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]**, [Table 96](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements) has the following entry (bold emphasis mine):

| Expression | Return Type | Operational Semantics | Assertion/note | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| `X::iterator` | iterator type whose value type is `T` |  | any iterator category that meets the forward iterator requirements. ***convertible to `X::const_iterator`.*** | … |

So, in your call to `.erase()`, the first argument is being converted to a `string::const_iterator`.

Thus, the bug is in those compilers that *don't* accept your call, assuming you have set them also to use the C++11 (or later) standard.

Comment: note that OP is missing `#include <string>`. If that fixes the error then it isnt a bug.

Comment: @AdrianMole : Sorry, forgot to include #include string. The error persists even when I include it. If Iterators are convertible to const_iterator then this is definitely a bug.

Comment: @john OK, I've edited-out the bit about that include, which I edited-in earlier. :)